# How to load multiple external .swf file in flash3.0 using for loop

Tags: flash

My file name is slider_1_1.swf. But once complete file then user next button click load in slider_1_2.swf this use in loop function. Someone help me.

Answer (score 0):

I think here's what you're looking for:

http://www.beautifycode.com/the-finer-art-of-loading-2-handling-multiple-swfs

Just do it with arrays, and that's about it.